# Why does my forked child process exit immediately after I fork it?

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm just trying to fork a simple child process and have the IPC channel stay open but it keeps exiting immediately for some reason.

In parent.js:

```
var child = require('child_process').fork('./child.js');
child.on('hi', function() {
    console.log("Hi");
});

child.on('exit', function() {
    console.log("Exited");
});

child.send('hello');
```

In child.js:

```
process.on('hello', function() {
    process.send('hi');
});
```

I get "Exited" printed to the console immediately, and never get a 'Hi'. Then if I continue to try to send to the child process I get a channel closed error.

Something I am doing wrong?

Comment: i think this is happening because your child process is finishing.  Something in the child process would need to keep the process running.

Comment: I tried adding a garbage `setInterval()` to it to keep it alive, and still no dice

Comment: try `process.stdin.resume();`

Comment: In child.js? I just tried, still nothing :(

Comment: did you put the `setInterval()` in the handler? i can get the process to stay alive if i put it outside the handler in `child.js`, but the message sending is still not working.

Comment: you need to listen to `message` in the child, not on some arbitrary string like `hello`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep both processes open as a child will close immediately and so will the parent.  You can do so with something like this:

parent.js

```
var child = require('child_process').fork('./child.js');

child.on('message', function () {
  console.log("Hi");
});

child.on('exit', function () {
  console.log("Exited");
});

setTimeout(() => {
  child.send('hello');
}, 1000);


process.stdin.resume();
```

child.js

```
process.on('message', function () {
  console.log("sending hi");
  process.send('hi');
});
```

Comment: also, im not sure arbitrary event names work.  seems like it must be "message"

Comment: ohhhhh i got it working :) turns out it was the event name - thought it could be anything but like you said it has to be "message"